# Distribution of Maximum Eigen Value

Tags: multicollinearity, eigenvalues, condition-number

Suppose I have X, k*n, where $M=X'X$. Suppose $n>>k$, and $rank(M) =k-1$. Suppose $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_{k-1}$ are the eigen values of M. Under the assumption that the columns of X are random, what can we say about the distribution of $\lambda_{max}$?

Here is my applied problem. Suppose the columns of X are observed values of n random variables. We only have k observations for each variable. I want to know if there exists an underlying variable that can explain them. If there is none, then $\lambda_i$ should be close to $\frac{1}{k-1}$. I want to know how large $\lambda_{max}$ has to be for us to conclude that at least one significant explanatory variable exists. This is similar to the condition number concept, except for the fact that M is not of full rank.

Edit: take n=2000, k=21.

Comment: $M$ isn't full rank?

Comment: Yes, it is not.

Comment: What distributions do the columns of $X$ follow? If all distributions are fair-game, I have written a simulation where two different distributions produce wildly different sets of maximum eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: Assume Gaussian with fat tails

Comment: What does that mean? Gaussians do not have fat tails (at least not compared to Gaussians). Even different Gaussians are giving me radically different maximum eigenvalue distributions, though.

Comment: The observed data is symmetric around mean, with fat tails. Does not fit any distribution perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There seems not to be a universal distribution of this maximum eigenvalue. In the simulation below, I draw from $t_5$ and $t_6$ distributions to create the first twenty columns of $X$. Then I create the 21st column by adding some of the first twenty columns. This meets the criteria set out in the question

Even just changing the degrees of freedom in the $t$-distribution results in wildly different distributions of the maximum eigenvalue of $X^TX$.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 2000
k <- 21
R <- 10000
B <- rbinom(k-1, 1, 0.3)
e1max <- e2max <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  X1 <- matrix(rt(N*(k-1), 5), N, k-1)
  Xk1 <- X1 %*% B
  X1 <- cbind(X1, Xk1)
  M1 <- t(X1) %*% X1
  e1 <- eigen(M1)
  e1max[i] <- max(e1$values)
  
  X2 <- matrix(rt(N*(k-1), 6), N, k-1)
  Xk2 <- X2 %*% B
  X2 <- cbind(X2, Xk2)
  M2 <- t(X2) %*% X2
  e2 <- eigen(M2)
  e2max[i] <- max(e2$values)  
}
d1 <- data.frame(
  Eigenvalue = e1max,
  Distribution = "t5"
)
d2 <- data.frame(
  Eigenvalue = e2max,
  Distribution = "t6"
)
d <- rbind(d1, d2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = Eigenvalue, fill = Distribution)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.25)
```

(This took a few minutes to run, but the time can be decreased by decreasing the number of repetitions `R`.)

[image: compare distributions of eigenvalues]

If you want to say something about the distribution of maximum eigenvalues in your particular situation, your best bet might be to bootstrap the rows of $X$, multiply to give some kind of bootstrapped matrix $M_{\text{boot}}$, and calculate the maximum eigenvalue of that boostrapped matrix. I give an example below.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 2000
k <- 21
R <- 10000
B <- rbinom(k-1, 1, 0.3)

X <- matrix(rt(N*(k-1), 5), N, k-1)
Xk <- X %*% B
X <- cbind(X, Xk)
emax <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  
  idx <- sample(seq(1, N, 1), N, replace = T)
  X_boot <- X[idx, ]
  M_boot <- t(X_boot) %*% X_boot
  e <- eigen(M_boot)
  emax[i] <- max(e$values)
  
}
d <- data.frame(Eigenvalue = emax, Distribution = "Bootstrap")
ggplot(d, aes(x = Eigenvalue, fill = Distribution)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.25)
```

[image: bootstrap distribution of maximum eigenvalues]